# how to prevent accepts_nested attributes_for from doing unnecessary validations in rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using accepts_nested_attributes_for in Rails 2.3.5 and find it does unnecessary validations on save.
In my application I have thousands of records so this is a problem.

To ilustrate this, I prepared a simple example.

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phrases
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phrases
end

class Phrase < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :value
  belongs_to :language
  def before_validation
    print "\nValidating: #{self.value}\n"
  end
end

$ script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.5)
>> lang = Language.first
=> #<Language id: 1, name: "Italiano">
>> lang.phrases
=> [#<Phrase id: 7, value: "Buona notte", language_id: 1>,
#<Phrase id: 10, value: "Ciao", language_id: 1>,
#<Phrase id: 11, value: "Prego", language_id: 1>]

>> lang.phrases_attributes = [{:id => "7", :value => "Buon giorno"}]
=> [{:value=>"Buon giorno", :id=>"7"}]
>> lang.save

Validating: Buon giorno

Validating: Ciao

Validating: Prego

=> true
```

As this example shows it is validating not only the child that was added, but all other children.
Am I missing something?
How can I avoid doing all these validations?
As i indicated earlier, this is a real handicap for a large app.

Comment: Do you only want to add one child at once!? If so, you should properly add them by `lang.phrases.build` instead of always assigning a new array for the whole association collection...

Comment: By mistake I wrote added. I meant updated. However, accepts_nested_attributes_for uses this same mechanism from a view and controller, which sometimes adds or updates.

Answer (score 0):

After a suggestion I received from a Jason King of the SDRuby group I tried updating to 2.3.18.
That solved the problem